# checking the details of a loop results

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck trying to find how to get results when checking the results of an array.

In my array, I have three coins that when tossed, the results are either Heads or tails based on the random number returned. If the random number is less than 0.5 its heads and if > than 0.5 its Tails.

If all three tosses are < 0.5 the console should print out the "Old Yang line". Else if >0.5 then " Old Yin line ".

how do I check through the loop to find if the results are two (<0.5) and one (>0.5) as an example?

here is my code:

```
public class BookOfChange {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Coin Coin1 = new Coin();
    Coin Coin2 = new Coin();
    Coin Coin3 = new Coin();

    double firstThrow = Coin1.getFace();
    double secondThrow = Coin2.getFace();
    double thirdThrow = Coin3.getFace();
    /**
     * Test method
     */
    System.out.println(Coin1.getFace());
    System.out.println(Coin2.getFace());
    System.out.println(Coin3.getFace());

    double[] toss = {firstThrow,secondThrow,thirdThrow  };
    /**
     * Test array
     */
    System.out.println(toss);

    for(int i = 0; i < toss.length; i++)
    {
    if(toss[i]<0.5) {

        System.out.println(" Old Yang line");
    }
    else if(toss[i]>0.5) {
        System.out.println(" Old Yin line ");
    }
    }
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just check the condition of first, second and third throw directly? See me example.

Also you are calling System.out.println(toss), to display the elements in an Array you need to use the Arrays.toString(ArrayName) method.

```
if(firstThrow < 0.5 && secondThrow < 0.5 && thirdThrow < 0.5) {
    System.out.println("Old Yang line");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Old Yin line");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley, and two check if the various throws are different will just need to tweak the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    int count_line = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toss.length; i++)
    {
        if(toss[i]<0.5) {
            count_line = count_line+1;
            System.out.println(" Old Yang line");
        }
        else if (toss[i]>0.5) {
            System.out.println(" Old Yin line ");
        }
    }

    if (count_line == 2){
        //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coin Coin1 = new Coin();
    Coin Coin2 = new Coin();
    Coin Coin3 = new Coin();

    double firstThrow = Coin1.getFace();
    double secondThrow = Coin2.getFace();
    double thirdThrow = Coin3.getFace();

    double[] toss = {firstThrow,secondThrow,thirdThrow  };
    int countYang = 0, countYin = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < toss.length; i++) {
      if(toss[i]<0.5) {
        countYang++;
      } else {
        countYin++;
      }
    }

    if (countYang > countYin) {
         System.out.println(" Old Yang line");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" Old Yin line ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int headCount = 0;
        int tailCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < toss.length; i++) {
            if (toss[i] < 0.5) {
                headCount++;
            } else if (toss[i] > 0.5) {
                tailCount++;
            }
        }
       if (headCount == 3)
        System.out.println(" Old Yang line");
       else if (tailCount == 3)
        System.out.println(" Old Yin line ");
       else if(headCount == 2 && tailCount ==1)
        System.out.println("Print ");
```

Comment: this code doesnt work for 2 out of 3 toss scenarios

Comment: @VishnuV you can check that by the variables headCount and tailCount. The value of each variable says the number of occurrence of head and tail.

Comment: Thank you @Prog_G that does work for me though when I  want to check the order of the results say: Heads,Heads and a Tail.

Answer (score 0):

This is an another way :

```
    int count_line = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toss.length; i++)
    {
        if(toss[i]<0.5) {
            count_line++;
        }
        if (count_line >= 2){
           System.out.println(" Old Yang line");
           break;
        }
    }
    if(count_line < 2)
    {
       System.out.println(" Old Yin line ");
    }
```